# Dictionaries inside a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, passwords

I'm trying to place dictionaries inside a larger dictionary to create a log in system

```
if(os.path.exists('Users.dat')):  
    with open('Users.dat','rb')as f:        
        Users = pickle.load(f)
        f.close()
done=False
while not(done):
    userin = input('Username: ')
    passin = input('Password: ')
    if userin in dict:
        usernames = Users[userin]['Username']
        passwords = Users[userin]['Password']
    else:
        break
```

when i do this it returns this:

```
Username: JTomkins12
Password: 4621
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\james\Lessons\Computing\Aptana Studio Workspace\Full
Program\FullProgram.py", line 274, in <module>
    loginmenu(choice)
  File "C:\Users\james\Lessons\Computing\Aptana Studio Workspace\Full
Program\FullProgram.py", line 255, in loginmenu
    if userin in dict:
TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable
```

can somebody help me fix this please?

Comment: You probably mean `userin in users:`

Comment: According to [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) you should use `users` as a name for the variabele. The capitalized version `Users` would be a class name.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking if the username is in the `dict` constructor type.

You want

```
if userin in Users:
     ...
```

To conform to the style guides, you should use lowercase names for variables, and reserve capitalized first letter names for class names.

It's typically considered more Pythonic to use `dict.get()` rather than check if the key is in the dict (on the principle that it's easier to ask forgiveness than permission), but what you're doing is a little more complex, so I'm not going to be critical.

Comment: Thanks, since you're newer to the site, you can accept my answer (checkmark next to it) and you'll get 2 rep for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

If you type the following in the shell, you'll see what's wrong:

```
>>> dict
<type 'dict'>
```

That means you're checking if a variable is inside a type, hence the `TypeError`.

You meant to type:

```
if userin in Users:
```

*(But like Matthias said, PEP8 would rather you call it `users`.)*